# No colors in terminal when booting raspbian in text mode

Tags: bash

I am booting my pi as text with autologin.

Even after modifying the `bashrc` file in the /home/pi folder, I still see the text in white.
I know that the color is enabled, because during the boot, I see the OK in green, so the terminal seems enabled for color, but nothing show up when I run `ls -la` or other commands.

What am I missing? I did enable `force_color_prompt=yes` in `bashrc`; and uncommented the lines where the aliases include the `--color=auto`l but still nothing happen.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261427/debian-how-to-change-terminal-background-colors

Comment: what response does `echo $TERM` get you?

Comment: your question has nothing to do with the RPi ... it is a Linux question .... research debian linux terminal colors

Comment: @jsotola please point me to where I said that this was a RPI issue. Please take time to read a question, if you are going to reply.

Comment: @tlfong01 Sadly not; that one refer to the terminal app in X11; I am running in pure terminal. I have no color except when the Pi boot up raspbian; that's the only time I see some green in the text. Also I have fully enabled the color options in `bashrc` so I am not sure what is missing there. Just as example, on OSX I can see colors no problem when I open terminal, after enabling  `export CLICOLOR=1` and setting `LSCOLORS` but on Raspbian I can't get the same (I assume because Raspbian is pure console terminal while OSX terminal run inside OSX GUI?)

Comment: @Jasen When I try that I get nothing back. The variable is empty

Comment: jstotola is correct that this issue is not pi specific, and you will have better luck if you research it that way (eg., do **not** include "raspberry pi" in your search terms).

Comment: @goldilocks did you read the question? I never said it happen only on raspberry pi or that it is a raspberry pi issue. I said I HAVE a raspberry pi with RASPBIAN and the changes to the bashrc does not trigger the color. Since I am using the pi and raspbian, logic dictate that asking on the pi exchange has more chances to find someone that did experience the same issue.

Comment: there's probalby more skill to address this problem in the "unix and linux"  stack exchange as the TERM variable is common to all of that.  it supposed to be automatically set , but I am not sure how that is meant to happen.

Comment: Dear all, please be reminded of the [*be nice* policy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/conduct). Note what [comments](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) are supposed to be used for and what not, i.e. comments should not be used for *Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point* or *Discussion of community behavior or site policies*. Comments are furthermore most certainly not the place for rants.

Answer (score 2):

The terminal emulation also plays a role with colors on the text console. I just don't know how it is set by default because I set it always to **linux**. You can get your setting with:

```
rpi ~$ echo $TERM
```

Try to set it in ~/.profile as first command:

```
TERM=linux
```

then logout/logon and look if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out today. As now the `$TERM` variable is empty

Comment: Hi @Jasen, you tried to add ´export TERM` to the answer. Sorry, but I haven't accepted it because it is not needed. `~/.profile` is a login file similar to `~/.bashrc`. It is sourced to the calling bash so there is no need to export environment variables when set in `~/.profile`.

Comment: @rataplan, Just now I did the following: (1) login to GUI DeskTpo, (2) switch to text terminal <ctrl-alt-F1>, (3) ls -la and saw a colourful list. 
https://imgur.com/gallery/dn18IJB Does it mean my config (rpi3B=, stretch 9) can do what your config cannot do?

Comment: @rataplan, I also booted to CLI, and found "$ ls -la" colourful.  "$ who" replied "pi tty1, ..."  tlfong01  2019jun18hkt1559